# Is a #10 wire circuit on a 50A breaker ok?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit

I have a Titan water heater that is 54 amps and is connected by a #10 wire to a 50 amp breaker. Will there be any problem?

Comment: Even if by some miracle you were operating at the 90° C rating, #10 THHN-2 would only be good for 40A. In your case the #10 copper wire is probably rated with an ampacity of 30A.

Comment: And in the end it doesn't matter what NEC says, **the installation manual says 6 AWG**. (Which happens to match NEC, but even if it didn't, it would still be the final rule.)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You can't just make an unqualified "the instructions rule" declaration. That works *only* if the instructions are approved by UL (or an equivalent body). Given the use of "220V" in their literature, I'm skeptical. 220V hasn't actually existed in the US in decades. 54A at 220V means 4.07Ω, which is 59A at 240V (the actual nominal standard now) or just over 60A at 245V (actual voltage that can be seen if you're close to your local transformer).

Comment: They even acknowledge the voltage issue on https://tanklesswaterheater.com/titanscr2-electronic-digital-tankless-water-heater.html but don't say anything about what to do in a 240V setup.

Comment: Finally, they claim a UL file number of E212386 but I can't find that in the UL database.

Comment: @nobody You are correct that "the instructions rule" only applies if the product is properly approved by UL or ETL etc. My point is really that whether you look at the standard ampacity charts or the instructions that come with the device, the end result is 6 AWG. Yes, if the instructions said 4 AWG and you thought 6 AWG was enough you could argue that to an inspector, but very possibly lose. And yes, if the instructions said 8 AWG even though normal ampacity charts said 6 AWG then if you installed 8 AWG and the inspector allowed it (clearly there was no inspection here, as 10 AWG would never

Comment: have passed inspection) and then there was a fire then it could get to an interesting liability/insurance fight. But the bottom line is NEC says 6 AWG, instructions say 6 AWG, so 10 AWG is flat out wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Yes there will be a problem. If the wires are in conduit they will probably over heat, melt the insulation, short out phase to phase and hopefully trip the breaker or possibly burn in the clear. If using NM cable, It will probably melt the insulation, arc and start a fire and maybe burn in the clear. You need to get this corrected and not use it until you do.

Depending on how fast you do a permanent fix, this unit has two elements. You could get someone who knows what they are doing and temporarily disconnect one of the elements lowering the amperage to 27 amps (at 220V per specs) and replace the breaker with a 30 amp one. This will still be more than the regular heater that was originally there but will be safe to use. The drawback is your hot water won't last as long or be as hot.

Answer (score 12):

##### TL;DR You May Have Even Bigger Problems

10 AWG wire indicates you likely had a standard tank water heater on a 30A circuit. You replaced it with a 54A tankless water heater, which according to [the installation manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/85/85c0c5a1-3562-4c41-86a9-9a42b771007b.pdf) requires a 60A breaker and 6 AWG wire. Based on an [Ampacity Chart](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) that is correct. Since it is not a continuous load, it only needs a 55A breaker, but those are not available. So instead you get a 60A breaker (not the 50A that you currently have) but the wire only has to satisfy 55A rules, which means 6 AWG NM cable or 6 AWG 75 C wires - either way, 6 AWG.

So keeping this on 10 AWG wire is:

- Against normal NEC rules
- Against manufacturer directions
- A **real fire hazard**

But wait, there's more!

Your electric service, panel size, etc. was based on a Load Calculation. That includes various required circuits, fixed appliances (e.g., water heater), HVAC, etc. That gets you a number (in Amps @ 240 Volts) representing the expected maximum power requirements for your house. That was originally based on a 4500W or 5500W tank water heater - at most 23A. Now you have added another 31A (or possibly more). If, for example, you have 100A service and an original load calculation of 70A, you are now at serious risk of overloading your service. Or if you have 200A service and had 120A and then added EV charging and a bigger oven and now tankless then you might be over 200A. Etc.

**Before investing in replacement cable/wire for this tankless water heater, figure out if you can safely use it on your existing service at all!**

Comment: Wow... this is a tankless!!!???  A 55A tankless is going to be about as useful as a chocolate teapot... just not enough for a house, not nearly, unless it's feeding one single shower with a California showerhead.  Over about 1.5 GPM the water will just go tepid.